# Retrieving and Updating values using Sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to know how can shared preference can be used to keep my data persistent and also update the values.I have written some code.

MainActivity.java

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs= this.getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sPrefs.contains("userData"))
        {
            retreivepreviousdata=gson.fromJson(sPrefs.getString("userData",""),DataStore.class);
            userDataStore.getDataStore().addAll(retreivepreviousdata.getDataRetrieve());
        }
            userDataStore.getDataStore().add(usrData);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            String saveData = gson.toJson(userDataStore);
            prefEditor.putString("userData", saveData);
            prefEditor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
```

SecondActivity.java

```
String mypreference="user_data";
    SharedPreferences sPrefs= this.getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    DataStore dataPull=new DataStore();
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String pull=sPrefs.getString("userData","");
    dataPull=gson.fromJson(pull,DataStore.class);
    System.out.println(dataPull.getDataStore().get(0).toString());
    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    MyRecyclerAdapter mAdapter=new MyRecyclerAdapter(dataPull);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The problem with this code is the values entered are saved and persistent.But when i close,reopen the app and enter values the previous data gets override.

Answer (score 0):

For Storing the value into SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("user_Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
            editor.putString("key", value);
            editor.commit();
```

For retrieving values from SharedPreferences just use this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user_Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = sharedPref.getString("key", "defaultValue");
```

Comment: how do we do it in case of array list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an ArrayList inside SharedPreferences, just convert it to a string. Then, you can "deconvert" it. E.G.

```
String toSave;
// Object is for your object type. Just get your objects converted to string, that's the point.
for(Object obj : arrayList){
    toSave += obj.toString() + "\n";
}
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("key", toSave);
editor.apply();
```

and...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String toGet = prefs.getString("key", "");
String[] parts = toGet.split("\n");
for(String s : parts){
    arrayList.add(s); // or do whatever conversion you want to get your Object type
}
```